# Can I use multiport option for load balancing through iptables?

Tags: iptables, load-balancing

I am trying to load balance using iptables.

My rules look like below:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -m statistic --mode nth --every 6 --packet 0 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5890

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -m statistic --mode nth --every 5 --packet 0 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5891

.

.

.

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -m statistic --mode nth --every 1 --packet 0 -j REDIRECT --to-port 5896

Can I use multiport option to consolidate the six rules into a single one?

Comment: are you sure there's not a cut/paste error? same destination port and same redirection port for every rule... I don't see how there's any load-balancing done with this configuration. Also a REDIRECTed destination is always local (the system running iptables) and won't be routed. Is that what you want for load-balancing?

Comment: corrected, that was a typo. my intention is to redirect any packet that comes to 5000 to six other ports in a round robin way. In a way its internal port load balancing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiport *match* is used as selector. There's no multiport option for the *TARGET* REDIRECT.
If you try to put a port range in the `--to-ports` option of REDIRECT, only the first port in the range will be chosen. Same if you (manage to) use `-j DNAT --to-destination` rule instead of REDIRECT. There won't be round-robin used.

The method you're currently using with iptables is certainly the way to go. The only minor optimization I can see is that you don't need `-m statistic --mode nth --every 1 --packet 0` on the last rule, because it always matches, and that `--packet` defaults to 0 so can be omitted everywhere.

Note: an other possible method would be by using ipvs (aka lvs) but it's certainly overkill especially for a local redirection, if at all possible for this case.